# Submit button doesn't run function in panel add-on sdk

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an add on using mozilla's add-on sdk. I have a panel attached to a toggle button that contains one input text box and a submit button. When the user presses enter, I am able to get my function to work. However, when I press the submit button nothing happens. Why is this? I have attached my code below:

```
// When the user hits return, send the "text-entered"
// message to main.js.
// The message payload is the contents of the edit box.
var textArea = document.getElementById("numTimes");
textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function onkeyup(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    // Remove the newline.
    text = textArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    self.port.emit("text-entered", text);
    textArea.value = '';
    console.log("Got text from enter");
  }
}, false);
// Listen for the "show" event being sent from the
// main add-on code. It means that the panel's about
// to be shown.
//
// Set the focus to the text area so the user can
// just start typing.
self.port.on("show", function onShow() {
  textArea.focus();
});

var submit = document.getElementById("search");
submit.addEventListener("click", function submit(){
    text = textArea.value.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
    self.port.emit("text-entered", text);
    textArea.value = '';
    console.log("Got text from submit button");
}, false);
```

The code that's within the textArea section works but the code by the submit section doesn't. Does JavaScript treat these differently?

Comment: Can someone please help me answer this?

Comment: You got good work going on here, i dont know why the sdk devs are dormant ill try to get someone here.